# Lenovo Y50-70 - Black laptop do not wake up after suspend.

Tags: 15.10, suspend

Once I suspend my laptop, do not goes back to work. The computer **still freeze** when I tray to go back from a suspension and is not possible put it in  low power consumption mode, because still working all the time.